# value stored during initialization is never read

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am trying parse the google api so that I can retrieve the address and its data. 
 I get two errors that are on the commented lines. Why am I getting these errors. 
 I allocated the dit so I should have to release it correct.
Here is my code to retrieve the data

```
  NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:str];
    NSData *data=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSString *str1=[[[NSString alloc]initWithData:data  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]autorelease];
    NSDictionary *dit=[[[NSDictionary alloc]init]autorelease];//value stored to dit during initialization is never read
    dit=[str1 JSONValue];
    NSArray *dit1=(NSArray *) [dit objectForKey:@"results"];
    NSDictionary *dit3=[[dit1 objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"geometry"];
    NSDictionary *dit4=[dit3 objectForKey:@"bounds"];
    NSDictionary *northeast=[dit4 objectForKey:@"northeast"];
    NSDictionary *lt=[northeast objectForKey:@"lat"];
    NSDictionary *southwest=[dit4 objectForKey:@"southwest"];
    NSDictionary *lng=[southwest objectForKey:@"lng"];
```

Comment: Where is your error, and what errors are you getting? There is no commented out text in what you posted.

Comment: Generally that "error" is only a warning, indicating that a variable is unused.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly allocate the `dit`, try to NSLog `str1` and `dit` after `dit=[str1 JSONValue];`, there also no highlight of the line where you have the problem, are you partly able to retrieve the data from `dit` ?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the issue is this:

```
NSDictionary *dit=[[[NSDictionary alloc]init]autorelease];
dit=[str1 JSONValue];
```

You create an empty dictionary, then never use it but instead overwrite the value with the one returned from JSONValue. This code should be:

```
NSDictionary *dit=[str1 JSONValue];
```